# Call React Component From Function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Have a simple react app, when a login is bad, or when anything happens where I would like to alert the user, I want to call a CustomAlert component.

In theory I should be able to pass the alert type and alert message to the component and it should show and then be closed if someone wants to click the X.

If I put the component on the page when I load, it does show so I know it's working, however if I try to call the component and show it dynamically from a function it will not show.

Here is an example.

Hit the login button without any credentials and you can see what will happen. It should have an alert box popup with a message. The console does log the phrase "call the message" on line 9 but it never shows the CustomAlert component.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dcneac?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your functions for `handleLoginChange` and `handleLogin` need to be inside of the App component. You are trying to setState on things that dont exist.

And for rendering the alert, all you need to do is conditionally render it within the App. You can't render it through a function. In the example bellow I have created a new state called message and when there is a message the alert will show.

```js
function CustomAlert(props) {
  const [severity] = useState(props.severity);
  const [message] = useState(props.message);

  return (
    <Alert
      onClose={() => {
        props.close();
      }}
      severity={severity}
    >
      {message}
    </Alert>
  );
}


export default function App() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState(null);

  const handleLoginChange = e => {
    if (e.target.name == 'email') {
      setEmail(e.target.value);
    }

    if (e.target.name == 'password') {
      setPassword(e.target.value);
    }
  };

  const handleLogin = () => {
    axios
      .post('https://someplace/api/logMeIn', {
        email: email,
        password: password
      })
      .then(response => {
        console.log('response', response);
        if (!response.data.error) {
          localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);
          setIsLoggedIn(true);
          setShowIntro(true);
        } else {
          setMessage({ type: 'error', message: 'Bad email or password'
          console.log('show the alert');
        }
      })
      .then(() => {
        getTemplates();
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('error', error);
        setMessage({ type: 'error', message: 'Bad email or password' });
      });
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setMessage(null)
  }

  return (
    <div className="login">
      {message && (
        <CustomAlert severity={message.type} message={message.message} close={handleClose}/>
      )}
      <Typography variant="h4" align="center" color="primary">
        Please Login
      </Typography>
      <form>
        <TextField
          id="email"
          label="Email"
          name="email"
          variant="filled"
          onChange={e => handleLoginChange(e)}
        />
        <TextField
          id="password"
          label="Password"
          name="password"
          variant="filled"
          type="password"
          onChange={e => handleLoginChange(e)}
        />
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          id="login"
          onClick={e => handleLogin(e)}
        >
          Login
        </Button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**EDIT**

What I have done now is edited the close event from the CustomAlert which calls a close props that calls a handleClose function within the App component which resets the state.

Comment: If you close the message and then type your email or password wrong a second time, it won't show the alert again. You need to null those values out somehow as well. @Richard Hpa

Comment: Yep you then need to pass a function from the CustomAlert component which clears your values

Comment: That was why I was asking for help, I wasn't sure how to do that. @Richard Hpa

Comment: Just made an edit. You need to look more at how to pass props between components

Comment: I know, thank you. Sometimes I just need to see and I had trouble reading through documentation or other tutorials.